# How are bound variables specified in an ArcGIS REST SOE?

Tags: arcgis-server, rest, server-object-extension

In the [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000m6r000000) for using handler functions with ArcGIS Server Rest SOE's, they don't explain how the keys in the boundVariables collection are determined.  When I search through the entire solution for "customLayersID" I don't see anything.  How would I know to use "customLayersID" as a key?

```
private byte[] CustomLayer(NameValueCollection boundVariables, string outputFormat,
    string requestProperties, out string responseProperties)
{
    responseProperties = null;

    //The LayerID.
    int layerID = Convert.ToInt32(boundVariables["customLayersID"]);

    //Execute.
    CustomLayerInfo layerInfo = GetLayerInfo(layerID);

    string json = layerInfo.ToJsonObject().ToJson();

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bound variable key takes the form of the **resource name** + "**ID**".

This is not very clearly stated in the conceptual document you linked to, but I remember seeing it somewhere.

EDIT: See [this PDF](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit10/papers/tech/extending_ags_services_using_.net.pdf), slide number 45. Resources seem to be always identified by their identifier (id), which is ok, but I personally find this string-convention-based design very weird. I should also note that the slides are a little outdated and do not exactly match the shipped version of the API.

One last (pedantic) complaint - ESRI will apparently never learn that id is not an abbreviation and as such should not be spelled in uppercase :-)